# Spectrum asymptotics for a product of $k$ random matrices?

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, st.statistics, random-matrices

How does the spectrum of a product of $k$ random matrices behave around 0?

In particular, I'm wondering if the CDF of squared singular values behaves as $x^{\frac{1}{k+1}}$ around 0. The result for $k=1$ comes from Marchenko-Pastur.

Below is a visualization of empirical CDF of squared singular values of a matrix formed by multiplying together $k$ square $1000\times 1000$ matrices with standard Normal entries.

[image]
[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mo-products-of-matrices.nb)

Unclear from simulation above is whether apparent "faster than power-law" decay is a finite sample effect or if it persists for $n\to\infty$. Any tips?

Motivation: a potential candidate for RMT model to match scaling laws observed in neural network training ([background](https://random-matrix-learning.github.io/#presentation3)). Shape of loss curve over time for $t\to \infty$ comes from shape of spectrum for $x\to 0$

Comment: yes, the $x^{1/(k+1)}$ scaling is the correct result.

Comment: For future reference, this result is in Eq 3.62 of Ipsen's [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distribution of the *singular values* has been studied in [Singular value correlation functions for products of Wishart random matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5694) and [Eigenvalues and Singular Values of Products of Rectangular Gaussian Random Matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3594). Near the origin the density of the squared singular values $x$ diverges as $\rho(x)\propto x^{-k/(k+1)}$, so a CDF that scales $\propto x^{1/(k+1)}$, as anticipated in the OP.

For completeness, I mention that the distibution of the *eigenvalues* of the product of $k$ random matrices has been studied in [Spectrum of the Product of Independent Random Gaussian Matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3422). It is circularly symmetric in the complex plane, with density $\rho(z)\propto |z|^{-2+2/k}$ in a disc of finite radius determined by the variance of the matrix elements. For $k=1$ one thus recovers the uniform density of the Ginibre ensemble.