# Random matrix models with squared singular value density diverging as $x^{-2}$ at 0

Tags: random-matrices

Are there named RMT models where the density of squared singular values diverges as $x^{-2+\epsilon}$ around 0?

Ginibre matrix has $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ decay, an infinite product of such brings it to $x^{-1}$ decay (references from Carlo in earlier [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450955/spectrum-asymptotics-for-a-product-of-k-random-matrices)). To match scaling laws observed when training neural networks, I need something around $x^{-1.9}$, wondering how I could go about obtaining such model.