# What does a product of many Gaussian matrices converge to?

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, st.statistics, random-matrices, free-probability

Let $A$ be a product of $n$ $d\times d$ matrices with  IID standard Gaussian entries and consider the value of $g(x)=x f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the density of squared singular values of $A/\|A\|$.

Is anything known about $g(x)$ in the $n\to \infty$, $d\to \infty$ limit, where $d$ limit taken first?

The effect of taking $n\to \infty$ limit first is better understood as such product is almost surely rank-1. Plotting $g(x)$ heuristically by relying on formula 3.61 from Ipsen's [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf) yields the chart below:

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-product-of-matrices.nb)

Empirically, I see the same density when considering matrices with Gaussian, symmetric Bernoulli and symmetric uniform entries so I'm wondering if the large $n$ limit has a name.

[image: This]

Comment: This is a slightly different problem (matrices are rectangular and main results is when outer dimension is small) but may be helpful https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/dwoodruf/www/lw21.pdf

Comment: Motivated by your added "free-probability" tag: To use multiplicative free convolution via the S-transform, the mean of the eigenvalue distribution would have to be positive - one could imagine shifting the semicircular distribution by a small amount $\epsilon $. Then, the S-transform can be given and taken to the $n$-th power. Re-extracting the corresponding eigenvalue distribution doesn't seem straightforward - I haven't made further progress in that direction. If you're interested in such a partial/failed attempt, I'll be happy to post it ... maybe someone sees how to take it further.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt S-transform of $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{(1+z)^n}$, right? (Eq 32 of [Burda](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2568)). What's not clear to me is 1) why does $\frac{1}{(1+z)^\infty}$, [give](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450956/7655) $1/x$ behavior at 0 and 2) how to get S-transform of $g(x)$

Comment: This formula of Burda is for the product of Wishart matrices, i.e., squares of Gaussian matrices. That seems to me to be different from what you're considering. For a Gaussian matrix, the S-transform is $1/\sqrt{z} $, and you'll have trouble inverting something like $1/z^{n/2} $. Hence the need for a shift by $\epsilon $ ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I've checked formula 35 which is density that Burda gets by inverting $\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ S-transform, and it [matches](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-burda-evals.nb) Ipsen's [formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf) 3.61 for eigenvalues of $XYY'X'$, which is squared singular values of $XY$, Gaussian $X,Y$

Comment: Ah, I understand the disconnect - I was thinking about the eigenvalue distribution of $XY$, which is different from what you want, you indeed want the eigenvalue distribution of $XYY^{\dagger } X^{\dagger } $, and that does correspond to convolving Wishart matrices. Ok, I understand what you're saying now. I'll think about what now follows - but it could be that in the end, it's a similar impasse to the one I met before...