# The distribution of product of normal matrices

Tags: pr.probability

Assuming we have three matrices:
$\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{4096 \times 1024}$,
$\mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{1024 \times 2048}$,
$\mathbf{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{2048 \times 1024}$.
Where all elements of these matrices are independently sampled from the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.We compute the matrix $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{K} \mathbf{X}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{4096 \times 4096}$ through matrix multiplication.
The question is: What distribution do the individual elements of the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ follow?How can we calculate its mean and variance?

Comment: at least for the spectrum there are some results see here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450955/spectrum-asymptotics-for-a-product-of-k-random-matrices eg. "Eigenvalues and Singular Values of Products of Rectangular Gaussian Random Matrices"

Comment: Thanks very much for your useful referrence.I still struggle in can we write an analytical solution for elements of matrix Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean of the matrix elements of $Y$ is zero, because the matrix elements of $Q$ and $K$ average to zero. The variance is given by
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{ip}^2]=\sum_{jkl\alpha\beta\gamma}\mathbb{E}[X_{ij} Q_{jk} K_{kl} X_{pl} X_{i\alpha} Q_{\alpha\beta} K_{\beta\gamma} X_{p\gamma}]$$
$$=\sum_{jkl}\mathbb{E}[(X_{ij} Q_{jk} K_{kl} X_{pl})^2]=2048\sum_{j,l=1}^{1024}\mathbb{E}[(X_{ij}X_{pl})^2].$$
If $i\neq p$ this evaluates to
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{ip}^2]=2048\times(1024)^2=2147483648.$$

For $i=p$ instead
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{ii}^2]=2048\sum_{j,l=1}^{1024}\mathbb{E}[(X_{ij}X_{il})^2]=2048\left(\sum_{j,l=1,j\neq i}^{1024}\mathbb{E}[(X_{ij}X_{il})^2]+2048\sum_{j=1}^{1024}\mathbb{E}[X_{ij}^4]\right)$$
$$=2048\cdot 1024\cdot 1023+2048\cdot 1024\cdot 3=2151677952.$$

*Concerning the full distribution:* The paper [The Product of Gaussian Matrices is Close to Gaussian](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09887) by Li & Woodruff considers the problem where all $N\times N$ matrices in the product are independent; then an $n\times n$ submatrix of the matrix product is close in variation distance to a matrix with uncorrelated Gaussian elements if $n^2\ll N$. I expect this result also to apply to the case considered here, where one matrix is repeated in the product. In particular, the marginal distribution of a single matrix element of $Y$ will be close to a Gaussian.

Comment: Do you have a proof that the distribution will be close to normal?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm curious to what distribution will the diagonal elements of Y satisfy?And I also want to kown why the distribution will be close to normal?According to CLF?

Comment: I added the variance for the diagonal elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!But I still have questions about why elements of $\mathbf{Y}$ close to a Gaussian.And does this also hold true for diagonal elements?Thanks once again for your generous response!

Comment: I added a reference where a similar problem is treated, which suggests that if you restrict yourself to the joint distribution of a small subset of the matrix elements of $Y$, this will be close to that of independent Gaussian random variables.

Comment: Thank you very much!Your reference is useful for me.